# ||x + y|| = 4 and ||x − y|| = 2. What is x · y? (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

- Background Information:

I am studying linear algebra, and for this question, I understand how to work with the formula of length/norm and dot product. However, I don't know how to approach this problem. I appreciate any hint, example, or explanation that can guide me to solve it. Thank you :)

- Question:

||x + y|| = 4 and ||x − y|| = 2. What is x · y?

Comment: Hint: note that $||x||=\langle x,x\rangle=x\cdot x$.

Comment: Is it possible to separate ||x + y|| from each other and turn it into ||x|| + ||y||?

Comment: Note that $\|x+y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 + 2x\cdot y$ and $\|x-y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 - 2x\cdot y$.

Comment: Hint: $\;\langle 2x, 2y\rangle = \left\langle (x+y)+(x-y), (x+y)-(x-y)\right\rangle\,$.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your suggestions, I learned how to do this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\Vert x + y \Vert^2 = (x+y).(x+y) = x.x + 2x.y + y.y = 16 $$
$$\Vert x - y \Vert^2 = (x-y).(x-y) = x.x - 2x.y + y.y = 4 $$
Subtract second from first:
$$2x.y + 2x.y = 16-4 =12$$
so 
$$x.y = \frac{12}{4} = 3$$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, it was all about knowing ∥x+y∥^2=(x+y).(x+y). I also suggested an edit, which adds more details to one of your steps and fixes 2 to 12.

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

$$\|x+y\|=4$$

If you square it,

$$\langle x+y, x+y\rangle =16$$

$$\|x\|^2+2\langle x, y\rangle +\|y\|^2=16$$

Do similar thing for the other equation as well and you caan solve for $\langle x, y \rangle$.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, it was helpful :)